# Pandoc: Is there a way to include an appendix of links in a PDF from markdown?

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc

I use Markdown and Pandoc extensively. However, I would like to generate a PDF with embedded links (like usual), but in the event the document is printed, I'd like to also include a table of links at the end of the document. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Ex.

```markdown
Title
-----


[Python][] is cool!

...

## Links ##
[Python]: http://python.org
[Pip]: https://pip.readthedocs.org
```

where I would actually get an extra page in my PDF with something like

```
Python: http://python.org
Pip: https://pip.readthedocs.org
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something that is easy to achieve with filters.

Here is `linkTable.hs`. A filter which adds a table of links to the end of your document.

```haskell
import Text.Pandoc.JSON
import Text.Pandoc.Walk
import Data.Monoid

main :: IO ()
main = toJSONFilter appendLinkTable

appendLinkTable :: Pandoc -> Pandoc
appendLinkTable (Pandoc m bs) = Pandoc m (bs ++ linkTable bs)

linkTable :: [Block] -> [Block]
linkTable p = [Header 2 ("linkTable", [], []) [Str "Links"] , Para links]
  where
    links = concatMap makeRow $ query getLink p
    getLink (Link txt (url, _)) = [(url,txt)]
    getLink _ = []
    makeRow (url, txt) = txt ++ [Str ":", Space, Link [Str url] (url, ""), LineBreak]
```

Compile the filter with `ghc linkTable.hs`. The output is as follows.

```markdown
> ghc linkTable.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( linkTable.hs, linkTable.o )
Linking linkTable ...

> cat example.md 
Title
-----


[Python][] is cool!

[Pip] is a package manager.

...

[Python]: http://python.org
[Pip]: https://pip.readthedocs.org
```

Then running `pandoc` with the filter.

```markdown
> pandoc -t markdown --filter=./linkTable example.md
Title
-----

[Python](http://python.org) is cool!

[Pip](https://pip.readthedocs.org) is a package manager.

...

Links {#linkTable}
-----

Python: <http://python.org>\
Pip: <https://pip.readthedocs.org>\
```